# How do I log out of an account on Steam for Android?

Tags: steam, android, steam-mobile

I have installed Steam for Android on my Nexus 7 tablet and logged into one of my Steam accounts (I have several). Now I'm trying to log out of that account to log into another but I cannot find the log out option.

On the main menu there is an "Exit Application" option, but this simply closes the application but doesn't actually allow you to change the currently logged in account. Starting Steam up again after exiting the application simply logs back into the same account again.

How do I log out of an account on Steam mobile?

Comment: In Steam for iOS, the very bottom menu option is "Log Out". I guess the Android version doesn't have that option?

Comment: @AdamV nope - retagged the question to make it more obvious this is for the Android version since there seem to be differences between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the menu and go to *Settings*. Next to your name, there should be a big *Sign Out* button. Click that.

[image: Image showing the "Sign Out" button on the "Settings" screen]

Answer (score 6):

To log out of an account in Steam for Android, you need to bring up the menu on the left side of the screen (either by pressing [image] or [image] buttons) and then go to "Settings". At the top right of the "Settings" screen there is a "Sign Out" button;

[image]

Tapping sign out will log you out of the current Steam account.